# Is it possible to run gRPC or HTTP/2 application in a AppEngine Managed VM?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, http2, grpc

I am trying to build a gRPC backend and trying to deploy it on an AppEngine Managed VM. Is HTTP/2 supported? If not, can I simply expose it on a separate port and disable health checks or should I deploy this on compute engine/container engine.

Comment: HTTP/2 is now available on GCP since last year. For your information your can visit this link http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2015/10/Full-Speed-Ahead-with-HTTP2-on-Google-Cloud-Platform.html

Answer (score 1):

At this point http/2 is not supported by Managed VMs. The best current solution is to run your http/2 server on a different port and specify the port number to forward in app.yaml ([doc link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/config#network_settings)).

You can keep health checking active on the default (8080) port if you want as long as you have an http endpoint listening there as well.