# Does Google App Engine support grpc bidirectional streaming?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, http2, grpc, bidirectional

We have backend services using grpc in Nodejs. Some of the services are in stream. We are looking for options for hosting the backend. It seems AWS Elastic Beanstalk does not support http/2. Any suggestions about hosting bidirectional grpc?

Comment: potentially related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142404/is-it-possible-to-run-grpc-or-http-2-application-in-a-appengine-managed-vm

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/borisovalex/enabling-googley-microservices-with-http2-and-grpc

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks! I don't see any details about deploying the services :(

Answer (score 0):

App Engine does not currently support HTTP/2 or gRPC backend services:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#not_supported

Sorry!

Comment: I believe you should be able to use a single GCE instance as an HTTP/2 target.  You could even use multiple instance behind a Network Load Balancer.  We do NOT support HTTP/2 over the L7 load balancer yet.